# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis - Following error is coming when i am putting Case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

`$`      The following code only highlights the where clause of BI Publisher query, in which i have an input paramter :P_COUNTRY, through which i am recieving the values either as PH/MY/CN on the basis of that i have to put the where clause.

```
WHERE     PRG.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID = PEU.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID
     AND PEU.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = PEE.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID
     AND PEE.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = PET.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID
     AND PRG.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
     AND PPSV.PERSON_ID = PPNF.PERSON_ID
     AND PPSV.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID
     --AND  PPNF.PERSON_ID  = CCPP.PERSON_ID
     AND PAAF.PRIMARY_ASSIGNMENT_FLAG = 'Y'
     AND PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
     AND PAAF.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID = PPOS.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID
     AND PPOS.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID
     AND PPOS.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = PLE.ORGANIZATION_ID
     AND PPNF.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'
     AND    (CASE   WHEN (:P_Country = 'PH') THEN (UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) IN ('PHCTC EXT'))
                    WHEN (:P_Country = 'MY') THEN (UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) IN ('MYCTC EXT'))
                    WHEN (:P_Country = 'CN') THEN (UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) IN ('CNCTC EXT'))
            END)
     AND PAAF.GRADE_ID = PG.GRADE_ID
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE clauses etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want would be more like:

```
WHERE     PRG.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID = PEU.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID
     AND PEU.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = PEE.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID
     AND PEE.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = PET.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID
     AND PRG.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
     AND PPSV.PERSON_ID = PPNF.PERSON_ID
     AND PPSV.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID
     --AND  PPNF.PERSON_ID  = CCPP.PERSON_ID
     AND PAAF.PRIMARY_ASSIGNMENT_FLAG = 'Y'
     AND PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
     AND PAAF.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID = PPOS.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID
     AND PPOS.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID
     AND PPOS.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = PLE.ORGANIZATION_ID
     AND PPNF.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'
     AND UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) =
            CASE   WHEN :P_Country = 'PH' THEN 'PHCTC EXT'
                   WHEN :P_Country = 'MY' THEN 'MYCTC EXT'
                   WHEN :P_Country = 'CN' THEN 'CNCTC EXT'
            END
     AND PAAF.GRADE_ID = PG.GRADE_ID
```

There is no need for all of the parenthesis you were using, and no need for the use of `IN` when you are only comparing one value.

Another alternative would be to do away with the `CASE` and use a series of grouped conditional clauses:

```
WHERE     PRG.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID = PEU.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID
     AND PEU.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = PEE.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID
     AND PEE.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = PET.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID
     AND PRG.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
     AND PPSV.PERSON_ID = PPNF.PERSON_ID
     AND PPSV.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID
     --AND  PPNF.PERSON_ID  = CCPP.PERSON_ID
     AND PAAF.PRIMARY_ASSIGNMENT_FLAG = 'Y'
     AND PAAF.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
     AND PAAF.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID = PPOS.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID
     AND PPOS.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID
     AND PPOS.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = PLE.ORGANIZATION_ID
     AND PPNF.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'
     AND (
        (:P_Country = 'PH' AND UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) = 'PHCTC EXT') OR
        (:P_Country = 'MY' AND UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) = 'MYCTC EXT') OR
        (:P_Country = 'CN' AND UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) = 'CNCTC EXT')
     )
     AND PAAF.GRADE_ID = PG.GRADE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case Expressions are Not Well Suited for the Where Clause**

You are using a [searched case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS278).  The results component of the case expression does not accept a boolean.

Here is the existing condition:

```
   AND    (CASE   WHEN (:P_Country = 'PH') THEN (UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) IN ('PHCTC EXT'))
                    WHEN (:P_Country = 'MY') THEN (UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) IN ('MYCTC EXT'))
                    WHEN (:P_Country = 'CN') THEN (UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) IN ('CNCTC EXT'))
            END)
```

I translate your case statement in words to the following:

*the bind variable, `:P_Country`, is being checked to see if it is in the `PET.ELEMENT_NAME`. More so, it is just the first segment of that `ELEMENT_NAME`.*

In SQL, I write:

```
AND UPPER(PET.ELEMENT_NAME) = :P_Country ||'CTC EXT'
```

Ideally it would be good to know if `ELEMENT_NAME` is all upper, lower, proper or mixed. One could modify the case of the bind variable to correspond with the `ELEMENT_NAME`.

You will get better performance.

for Example if we know `ELEMENT_NAME` is always UPPER case, we could do this:

```
AND PET.ELEMENT_NAME = UPPER(:P_Country) ||'CTC EXT'
```